# Start application when igniting Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

I'm currently creating an arcade cabinet project, so I used a Raspberry Pi 4 B or Raspberry Pi 3 B for this. The game is running on a web application.

I wanted to start the web application directly on full screen when igniting the Raspberry Pi, without PC sensation (OS authentication, OS desktop).

Does someone know how to start the web application directly on full screen when igniting the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Use a systemd service

Comment: This question might fit better at [raspberrypi.SE] or [SU] - see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=autostart or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=startup

Comment: SO is strictly for questions related to programming or use of a programmer's tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal write this code

sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

then ;

@chromium-browser --start-fullscreen  http://localhost     **full screen

@chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-infobars  http://localhost  **full screen and no error

and CTRL+X  , reboot...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).